# How do I plant crops newly acquired in trade?

Tags: banished

My village has squash and peppers natively and they're growing fine.  Traders brought wheat and I traded for 100 units of it, then designated a farm, but when I try to assign it to growing wheat, only my squash and peppers are options.  What's the trick?

ETA: A couple years later, a trader arrived with a single cherry tree seed.  I bought it and planted it with no problems.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you traded for 100 units of wheat product, not seed... you need to trade for the seed just like the cherry tree.

Comment: Ha, funny!  I assumed that since wheat *is* a seed that it was good to go.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No trick. You bought the crop itself, what is used by the people to eat, NOT the seed.  When you bought the cherry seed you unlocked the ability to grow cherries, but since you didn't buy the wheat seed, which costs 2250, your people just ate what you bought instead of you unlocking the crop to farm.